# ng-model problems in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write my first non-trivial directive and am having problems.

What I am trying to do is similar to http://plnkr.co/nYSBnm

This works as intended apart from the two inputs are using the same field.  When I try and get them to use the intended fields, by putting

```
ng-model="record.{{field.name}}"
```

in the formInput attributes to replace ng-model="record.name" I get an error

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [record.{{field.name}}] starting at [{{field.name}}].
```

For what it is worth the plunk is at http://plnkr.co/O2uosO27khbcxZEeEb6V

I have looked at various somewhat similar questions on here and stack overflow and so far failed to get anything to work.

I would be grateful for any light anyone can throw on it.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I had also asked this question on the AngularJS group (I posted here after a day or so of silence on there).  Then I got a response from Pawel Kozlowski who pointed out that

```
ng-model="record[field.name]"
```

"kind of starts to work" as he put it.  There is a plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOiJvkDI2akpV5LAV0yo?p=preview).

Not sure what he meant by his comment but when I put that in a real page and hit refresh I get two copies of the fields (unless I clear the cache), but he certainly solved the stated problem.