# Is it possible to use an Expression as part of the ng-model Directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="measure in CompleteDataSetViewModel.TargetMeasures">
</div>
```

Inside here I have an input like so:

```
<input ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.Target[measure.Name]_Original"
          class="form-control input-lg annualTargetInput"
          type="number"
          ng-change="spreadTotal(measure.Id); updatePercentage(measure.Id)" />
```

If I use {{ measure.Name }} in my loop it works fine, but I want it to be part of the ng-model directive for that input, so it would emit as `CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.TargetElectricity_Original` as this is how I must save it in the database.

I have tried both `ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.Target{{measure.Name}}_Original"` and `ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.Target[measure.Name]_Original"`

The former produces: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 45 of the expression. The latter method produces: **Syntax Error: Token '_Original' is an unexpected token at column 59**

I found an old [Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/5AIyZeFQ-Uk) that seemed to suggest the [measure.Name] method should work. Also [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304368/ng-model-problems-in-a-directive) and a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOiJvkDI2akpV5LAV0yo?p=preview).

It feels like it should work, but I need to do something with the _Original I must tack on the end of the property's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.Target[measure.Name + '_Original']"
```

Angular expression is technically a string of normal javascript code that can be interpreted, so you can use any valid (with some limitations Angular parser imposes) expression for it. So above should work for you.

Comment: Had some secondary issues to sort out. When I hit those and came back to this it was indeed correct to use the method described above. Very grateful for your help.

Comment: Have been working on this some more and have definitely concluding a slight amendment is needed. It should be: `ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord['Target' + measure.Name + '_Original']"` - note the removal of the dot after AnnualRecord.

Comment: That's right, I focused on square brackets part and missed that "Target" is also a part of the dynamic name. I thought that it's something like `AnnualRecord = {Target: { ... }}` structure.

Comment: Oh if only. That would be sensible, right? Instead I've got to prefix a target field with "target" even though they all live in a table called "targets"! Thanks for your help anyway, though, very much appreciated. I'm off to brush up on my JavaScript basics!